# Make VSCode autocomplete React props type as well as name?

Tags: reactjs, webstorm, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to migrate from WebStorm to VSCode. VSCode seems to autocomplete my prop names fine (I'm also using TypeScript), but one thing that I like about WebStorm is it not only autocompletes the prop name, it also adds the `=` and either `""` or `{}` (it uses TS to know what prop type it is and adds the appropriate thing).

So, for example, if I have a `Person` component that has `name` as a string, in WebStorm I can type `<Person` and hit tab when it auto-suggests "name", which will automatically have `<Person name=""` with my cursor in-between the quotes. Similarly, if `age` is a number it would have `<Person age={}` with my cursor between `{}`.

Does VSCode have a similar setting that I can set?

Answer (score 0):

Check if this is similar to [issue 33641](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/33641) which mentioned:

> In the corner it said it was running Typescript 2.0.0.
> I assumed that it would run whichever version of typescript my project declared in the `package.json` file.
>
> Clicking on that in the corner brought me to the page which explained that the `typescript.tsdk` user setting can be used to point to a specific typescript installation.
> After switching this setting and restarting VSCode, it said 2.4.2 in the corner and suddenly completion of React props started to work correctly.